# How to convert gtk3 theme for gtk4?

Tags: gnome, 22.04

I have old Yaru theme (from Ubuntu 20.04, dark head and light content) and I need use it in Ubuntu 22.04, but the system does not obey it, because most of the applications use gtk4. Hence my question.

Comment: I don't think you can simply "covert" a theme. But Yaru should have a gtk4 version as I read [here](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2021/02/ubuntu-yaru-theme-gtk4). And looking up [Yaru-remix](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1384810) (without testing because I'm on Kubuntu)) I see it contains gtk4 folder: https://github.com/Muqtxdir/yaru-remix/tree/master/gtk/src/default . But that should be true about Yaru: https://github.com/ubuntu/yaru/tree/master/gtk/src/default

Comment: you can create a new icon theme, using your old theme's icons.

Comment: It is a wrong assumption from your side to state that most of the applications in Ubuntu 22.04 use GTK4. That is not the case. You may want to remove that statement from your question.